# iPhone dev: Increase scroll speed in UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, scroll

I have an app in which I render local HTML files in a UIWebView. The files, however, are sometimes large, and getting to where you want takes a long time with the default scroll speed. Is there any way to boost up the vertical scroll speed of a UIWebView?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In iOS 5 we can access the `scrollView` property of the `UIWebView`.

If you are targeting iOS 5+, you can simply call:

```
webView.scrollView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateNormal;
```

Answer (score 7):

Find a subview of UIWebView which is a UIScrollView, then set ***decelerationRate*** to ***UIScrollViewDecelerationRateNormal***. This makes the UIWebView as fast as an ordinary UIScrollView.

In iOS 4/5, we can simply use the last subview of UIWebView.

```
UIScrollView *scroll = [webView.subviews lastObject];
if ([scroll isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
    scroll.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateNormal;
}
```

The default *decelerationRate* of UIWebView's UIScrollView is 0.989324, while *UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast* is 0.99, and *UIScrollViewDecelerationRateNormal* is 0.998.

This method doesn't use any private API.

Answer (score 2):

Search for a **subview** of UIWebView that responds to *-setScrollDecelerationFactor:* (it's UIScroller - a private class that's the only subview of UIScrollView). You'll find that it takes the same deceleration factors defined for the public UIScrollView class:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)aView {
    id decelerator = [aView viewWithSelector:@selector(setScrollDecelerationFactor:)];
    [decelerator setScrollDecelerationFactor:UIScrollViewDecelerationRateNormal];
}
```

Note that the method I'm using *viewWithSelector:* is a method I defined in a category of UIView. Presumably, if UIWebView changes in future, my search will return nil and this method will become a no-op.

Comment: I wasn't able to do this. I use the following code:

`for (UIView* subView in self.currentScrollView.subviews) {
       if ([subView respondsToSelector:@selector(setScrollDecelerationFactor:)]) {
           [subView setScrollDecelerationFactor:UIScrollViewDecelerationRateNormal];`

But that condition is never true. Any help?

Comment: My -viewWithSelector: method traverses the view hierarchy beyond subviews. UIScroller likely isn't a direct descendent of UIWebView, and so your code isn't finding it.

Comment: this will get your app rejected.

Comment: I'll have a look and see if an alternative solution has come up in the intervening years. It's a wart on the kit that the same physical action of swiping happens to lead to two different experiences depending upon whether you're in a web view or a scroll view.

Comment: Filed a bug with Apple on this: ref. no. 11322967

Answer (score 0):

Have considered adding # tags into your html on significant boundaries?

You could actually use native UI to implement bookmarks or a ToC for easier navigation, or simply embed links to the appropriate targets right in your html.

If you 'speed up scrolling' your app is at risk of rejection for being non-standard, since it may confuse users who are used to webviews scrolling with a standard 'feel'.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but these setting or trick really helped me even in 2018.

Follow these simple coding tricks to improve Android `WebView` Performance:

```
WebView mWebView = new WebView(this);
WebSettings settings = mWebView.getSettings();
settings.setSupportZoom(true);
settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
mWebView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);
settings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
settings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {

    mWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);

} else {
mWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
}
```