# Cannot change WKWebView's scroll rate on iOS 9 beta / 9.3

Tags: ios, scroll, wkwebview, ios9

On iOS 8, the below code works fine, it can scroll with more inertia.

`webView.scrollView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateNormal;`

As for iOS 9 beta 3, this code is meaningless, even without an error.
Is this a bug or are there any other ways around?

Note: UIWebView's scroll rate can be changed two types on both versions.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with iOS 9 GM

Answer (score 9):

Update: this has been fixed but not deployed in iOS 9.3 (see workaround below). More detail here:

- https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=148086
- http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/188541/trunk/Source/WebKit2/UIProcess/ios/WKScrollView.mm

---

I had the same issue and it seems to be a bug in iOS 9.

The workaround is to set it in the will begin dragging delegate instead of at the time of instantiation:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    scrollView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateNormal;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. You are our savior!

Comment: This is really great tip! Thanks a lot!

Comment: So, this worked great for me, until I realized my app became super unstable =S. After setting `webview.scrollView.delegate = self`, I started to get sporadic crashes... Anyone else experience this?

Comment: @shawnjan Mine seems fine so far. Maybe the crashes are not related to that but WKWebView internal stuff? Just guessing.

Comment: @shawnjan yeah my scrollview's scroll bar is glitching up and down. Did you end up resolving this?

Comment: This seems to be broken in iOS 11 (as of beta 2 / public beta 1). I can't set it to decelerate fast.

Answer (score -2):

I also used to get sporadic crashes, then I set

```
webview.scrollView.delegate = nil
```

in deinit.

Comment: This is a different issue / crash. More detail: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=159980