# Replicate persistent / fast scrolling like Chrome ios

Tags: ios, webview, uiscrollview, webkit, wkwebview

So I have a webview implemented using WKWebView. Scrolling is fine how it is, but I'm interested in having it behave like the Chrome app. I just don't really know how to make it happen.

I don't know if they are messing with animation duration, deceleration rate or what.

I've tried:

```
currentScrollView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateNormal;
currentScrollView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast;
```

Without really noticing a difference. I've also tried a few suggestions here on stackoverflow, but all it seems to do it just stop the scrolling animation altogether.

Another possibility is tapping into the CSS property of the webview and calling:

```
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

Don't really know how to call that. From some older code I used for a image viewer, I modified it as follows, without any effect:

```
NSString *css = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", @"<!DOCTYPE html>"
                 "<html lang=\"ja\">"
                 "<head>"
                 "<meta charset=\"UTF-8\">"
                 "<style type=\"text/css\">"
                 "html{margin:0;padding:0;}"
                 "body {"
                 "overflow-y: scroll;"
                 "-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;"
                 "margin: 0;"
                 "padding: 0;"
                 "background: clear;"
                 "}"
                 "</style>"
                 "</head>"
                 "</html>"];
[self.webView evaluateJavaScript:css completionHandler:nil];
```

But I'm not the greatest at modifying in this style.

Anybody have any ideas? Suggestions?

I don't care about Apple approval as I won't be submitting my app, so a hack, swizzle etc is fine by me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it might be a combo of both of what I post below, or 1 or the other, but I got it working in case anybody is interested.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.webView.scrollView setDecelerationRate:UIScrollViewDecelerationRateNormal];
}

- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    scrollView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateNormal;
}
```

---

Note: There is a bug on iOS 9 that causes this. More info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32843700/308315